# Linux removing folders older than 1 year and more than 3 files

Tags: linux, ant, ssh, find, archive

I'm writing an ant script to clean up an archive folder

Here's how I need to clean it up: I need to delete folders old than a certain amount of days AND has more than 3 files in it. So for example if a folder is 300 days old but only has 3 files than it will NOT be deleted.

I know I can ssh into the archive and do `find -mtime +365 -exec rm -rf {} ;\` to delete files older than 1 year but I don't know how to account for the minimum of 3 files

I also know that `find -type f | wc -l` will list the number of files, but that doesn't really help in terms of scripting

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

ANT [selectors](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html) enable you to customize the fileset to delete.

Try the following:

```
<target name="purge">

    <tstamp>
        <format property="touch.time" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aa" offset="-300" unit="day"/>
    </tstamp>

    <delete>
        <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
            <date datetime="${touch.time}" when="before"/>

            <scriptselector language="javascript"><![CDATA[
                if (file.getParentFile().list().length > 3) {
                    self.setSelected(true);
                }
                else {
                    self.setSelected(false);
                }
            ]]> </scriptselector>
        </fileset>
    </delete>
</target>
```

Comment: THANKS A LOT OF THE ANSWER. I'll test it out and let you know

Comment: How do i adjust the code so that I can execute this code on an remote server?

Comment: @JinAhn The ANT fileset will only work against local files. Is ANT installed on the remote server?

Comment: not it is not. I normally ssh into the the archive box and just run commmands. is there another way?