# Ant - Delete folder and subfolder if any of it has modified date < (currentdate - 6 months)

Tags: ant

Here is my situation:
I am having a folder, let's say C:\temp\parent\, that has many subfolders.
Each of these subfolder has only 1 zip file.
What I would like to do with Ant, is delete all the folders and its zip files where the modified date of those zip files is lesser than the current date minus 6 months.
Is there kind of an 'easy' way to do it?

Thanks a lot for your help,

Regards,

Thiago

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531631/linux-removing-folders-older-than-1-year-and-more-than-3-files/11547287#11547287

Comment: Thank you it really does help.
Just to understand a bit better, do I need the scriptselector part?
Furthermore, how can I say to iterate on all the zip files within the subfolder, and for those where the modified date < touch.time, delete the zip file and the containing folder?
Thanks!!

Comment: No I don't think so. That question was a little bit more complicated :-)

Comment: yes, my comments went to soon online ;)