# Ant - age of file

Tags: ant

Is there a way to check age of file during build process?

I would like to check if specified file is older than 1 week.

Something like

```
<olderthan property="property.name" file="checked.file" days="7"/>
```

I thought of using [touch](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/touch.html) and [uptodate](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/uptodate.html) but `touch` can use only specified date or `now`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux removing folders older than 1 year and more than 3 files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531631/linux-removing-folders-older-than-1-year-and-more-than-3-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mark's link didn't solved my problem but gave me idea to use script

```
<!-- Check if specified file is newer than age in seconds -->
<scriptdef name="isNewerThan" uri="composer.ant.mleko" language="javascript">
    <attribute name="file"/> <!-- The file to check. -->
    <attribute name="age"/> <!-- The threshold of file age in seconds. -->
    <attribute name="property"/> <!-- The name of property to set. -->
    <attribute name="value"/> <!-- The value to set the property to. Defaults to "true". -->
    <attribute name="else"/> <!-- The value to set the property to if the condition evaluates to false. By default the property will remain unset. -->
    <![CDATA[
        var fileName = attributes.get("file");
        var age = attributes.get("age");
        var property = attributes.get("property");
        var value = attributes.get("value");
        var elseValue = attributes.get("else");

        var maxAge = parseInt(age, 10);

        if(null === fileName)self.fail("`file` is required");
        if(null === age || isNaN(maxAge))self.fail("`age` is required and must be valid int string");
        if(null === property)self.fail("`property` is required");
        if(null === value)value="true";

        var file = new java.io.File(fileName);
        var ageInSeconds = (Date.now() - file.lastModified())/1000;

        if(ageInSeconds < maxAge){
            project.setProperty(property, value);
        }else if(null !== elseValue){
            project.setProperty(property, elseValue);
        }
    ]]>
</scriptdef>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use `<touch>` and `<uptodate>` together with `<tstamp>`:

```
<tstamp>
    <format property="one.week.ago" offset="-7" unit="day" pattern="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm aa"/>
</tstamp>

<touch file="source-file.txt" datetime="${one.week.ago}"/>

<uptodate 
    property="target-file-modified-in-previous-week" 
    targetfile="target-file.txt"
>
    <srcfiles dir= "." includes="source-file.txt"/>
</uptodate>

<condition property="is-target-file-out-of-date" value="true" else="false">
    <isset property="target-file-modified-in-previous-week"/>
</condition>

<echo>is-target-file-out-of-date: ${is-target-file-out-of-date}</echo>
```