# Using Apache Ant to Delete All But Most Recent 3 Directories

Tags: ant

I have a scenario in which there is an "archive" directory that contains various subdirectories.  I only want to keep the most recent three subdirectories.  So, for example I have:

```
archive/
  subA/    [created 1-May-2018]
  subB/    [created 2-May-2018]
  subC/    [created 3-May-2018]
  subD/    [created 4-May-2018]
  subE/    [created 5-May-2018]
```

In other words, I want to be able to select subA and subB (on the basis of their filesystem dates) and delete them -- including all files and subdirectories within them.  I can easily do a Python script that does this, but would prefer a pure-Ant solution.

Based on another StackOverflow question ([How to delete all but latest 2 files using Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29706777/how-to-delete-all-but-latest-2-files-using-ant)), I have tried:

```
<resources id="deleteDirs">
  <allbutlast count="3" >
    <sort>
      <date />
      <resources>
        <dirset dir="${dir.archive}" includes="*" />
      </resources>
    </sort>
  </allbutlast>
</resources>
<echo message="Delete directories: ${toString:deleteDirs}" />

<delete verbose="true">
  <resources refid="deleteDirs" />
</delete>
```

However this and any other variations I have come up with do not work.  Note, however, that the deleteDirs refid when printed out does show what I want selected, but the **delete** task quietly ignores it.

In briefly examining the source for the **delete** task, there are comments to the effect that the **delete** was at some point refactored to also perform the deprecated **deltree** task (which apparently cannot wrap around a resource, dirset, or path).  So, I am guessing that when **deltree** was brought into **delete** it still only works with the form:

```
<delete dir="DIRNAME"/>
```

and not when wrapping a resource collection.

Is there a pure Ant way to essentially do:

```
<deltree dir="${dir.archive}/subA" />
<deltree dir="${dir.archive}/subB" />
```

However, without hard-coding my selection(s) in **deltree** tasks and allowing Ant to select all but the most recent three directories based on date.

Comment: As far as I know there is no pure ant solution. But you could call your python (or any other) script using the exec-task of ant.

Comment: Thanks -- yes, scripting does get me around a lot of Ant's constraints; however, I generally prefer to avoid it if I can find a not too convoluted way of doing this kind of stuff directly in Ant.  Basically the code ends up being more maintainable by others if they are expected to only be well-versed in Ant.

Comment: I understand that, but I don't see how Ant could do that. If your directories would have less generic names you could target them by using regex, but even if that is an option for you, I would prefer running an external script for readability.

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck on the same problem. I am shocked that this problem is not solved for long. Apparently  task does not work with resource collection of type . The only solution to the problem I could figure out is to use ant-contrib and do the follwing:

```
    <for param="folder">
        <path>
            <allbutlast count="${to.keep.count}">
                <sort>
                    <dirset dir="${dir.archive}" includes="*"/>
                </sort>
            </allbutlast>
        </path>
        <sequential>
            <delete dir="@{folder}"/>
        </sequential>
    </for>
```

If anybody can suggest a solution without using Ant-Contrib, I will be (and I believe not only me) very very grateful.

Of course the perfect solution would be to make this work as follows:

```
    <delete verbose="true">
            <allbutlast count="${to.keep.count}">
                <sort>
                    <dirset dir="${dir.archive}" includes="*"/>
                </sort>
            </allbutlast>
    </delete>
```

but unfortunately this does not work.