# Apache ant character selector in filename copy task

Tags: regex, ant

For a fileset like this:

```
XXX_staging
    A_filename\A_filename.txt
    B_filenAme\B_filenAme.txt

XXX_AL_staging
```

The following ant target will copy only the files whose names start with an uppercase "A", from the XXX_staging folder to the XXX_AL_staging folder:

```
<target name="split_topics">
      <copy todir="XXX_AL_staging\" verbose="true" overwrite="true">
        <fileset dir=".\XXX_staging" includes="**/A*.txt">
        </fileset>
  </copy>
 </target>
```

What I want to do is copy only files whose names start with A through L. This doesn't work:

```
<target name="split_topics">
      <copy todir="XXX_AL_staging\" verbose="true" overwrite="true">
        <fileset dir=".\XXX_staging" includes="**/[A-L]*.txt">
        </fileset>
  </copy>
 </target>
```

I'm wondering if the problem is that the second is not just a wildcard match like the first, but a regular expression match, which won't work for a filename? I don't want to match the contents of the files, just the filenames, so containsregexp seems to be out.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Filename selectors](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html#filenameselect) can utilize a regular expression.

## Example 1

```
├── build.xml
├── src
│   └── somedir
│       ├── A_filename.txt
│       ├── B_filename.txt
│       ├── C_filename.txt
│       ├── D_filename.txt
│       ├── E_filename.txt
│       ├── F_filename.txt
│       └── G_filename.txt
└── target
    └── somedir
        ├── A_filename.txt
        ├── B_filename.txt
        ├── C_filename.txt
        └── D_filename.txt
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="copy">

  <property name="src.dir"   location="src"/>
  <property name="build.dir" location="target"/>

  <target name="copy">
    <copy todir="${build.dir}" overwrite="true" verbose="true">
      <fileset dir="${src.dir}">
        <filename regex="\/[A-D].*.txt$"/>
      </fileset>
    </copy>
  </target>

</project>
```

## Example 2

- [Copying files from source directory to destination directory using ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31705943/copying-files-from-source-directory-to-destination-directory-using-ant/31709378#31709378)

Comment: Okay that looks like what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, [ant patterns](https://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns) are not regular expressions, not even a little. They are wildcards with a very limited syntax. For a complex solution, you can use the ability to define your own task in Javascript and code something out, but this will not let you create an alternative file set pattern matching syntax.

Comment: Okay yeah, as I suspected, thanks. This works: `includes="**/A*.txt,**/L*.txt">` (a comma-separated list), so I could just list all the letters from A through L for now. Then maybe will do something with Javascript that I can insert.